# Does Fast Update Flow consume a SOQL when we use the dot-notation to populate fields?

Tags: visual-workflow, governorlimits, visual-flows

My question is, I have a Record-triggered fast flow on Opportunity. This is essentially a before-insert trigger context logic.

Now in my flow, I am using the provided traversal from Opportunity to Account field using the {$Record.Account.FieldName__c} route to populate the field value on Account on my Opportunity field.

Does this count as a SOQL, since I'd have had to use a query if I had done the same via apex? Also, is the flow bulkied by default?

Comment: As far as I can tell, formulas don't seem to use any SOQL limits. This is probably related to the fact that Flows already know what data they need, so they can pre-load them with the rest of the record data ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `{$Record.Account.FieldName__c}` will not count as additional SOQL. This is efficient way to use in flow without the need to  of  a SOQL query(Get record element).

In the way we bulkify apex by not writing SOQL or DML operations inside For loop in the same way we should avoid using get records or DML operation like delete record or update records inside Loop element. If we keep the above elements in Loop this will cause Governor Limits